How to rewrite using .htacess i need a ? in the link it is supposed to go to
For example my link is mydomain.com/weather-is-good and i need it to go to audiofile.com/s-1234?si=5678
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com€ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com€
RewriteRule ^weather\-is\-good€ "https\:\/\/audiofile\.com\/s\-1234\?si\=5678" [R=301,L]

gives me
/s-1234%26si=5678

I think the formatting of this post got corrupted when you copied it.  Should the "Euro Sumbol" be a $ ?

I think it should look like this:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^weather\-is\-good$ https://audiofile.com/s-1234?si=5678 [R=301,L]

We remove the quotes, add a dollar sign at the end of the URL for exact matching, and use the flag, in our case, a 301 redirect.
Check it out, seems like it should help.
